# Error #14 while trying to read CSV data

Tags: csv, highcharts

I'm trying to use Highcharts with following code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scriptaculous/lib/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Js/prototype-adapter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Js/modules/data.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='gfx' style="width:1024px; min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<pre id='csv'>Production,Duration
2014-10-27,2866,08.50
2014-10-28,6471,09.20
2014-10-29,7609,09.25
2014-10-30,7552,09.11
</pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            renderTo: 'gfx'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Daily statistics'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'date'
        },
        yAxis: [
            {
                title: { text: 'Watt hours' }
            },
            {
                title: { text: 'Hour.Minutes' },
                opposite: true
            }
        ],
        data: {
            csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
            firstRowAsNames: false
        },
        series:[]
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But HightCharts raised an error #14.
I tried to change float values to integers and/or use dateFormat: to force the date format, but all is failing.

So, where is my mistake ?

Thanks

Laurent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple of things going on here:

Your csv has titles and you've set firstRowAsNames as false

Your csv has 2 items in the title row, and you need 3

There isn't a "date" xAxis type.  It's "datetime"

You are not telling highcharts that you want your 2nd series mapped against your 2nd yAxis.

I left the fiddle using jquery instead of changing it to prototype, but the same code will work.

```
<pre id="csv" style="display:none">Date,Production,Duration
2014-10-27,2866,08.50
2014-10-28,6471,09.20
2014-10-29,7609,09.25
2014-10-30,7552,09.11</pre>


var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        renderTo: 'gfx'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Daily statistics'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'Watt hours'
        }
    }, {
        title: {
            text: 'Hour.Minutes'
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
        firstRowAsNames: true
    },
    series: [{
        yAxis: 0
    }, {
        yAxis: 1
    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c92acrvx/2/